# Rails RSpec test - prevent delete comment for user who is not the author of it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to test the 'destroy' action for my nested comments controller.

In my filmweb app I have scope and validations which prevents users from deleting a comment which is not the author. In web version everything works well but I don't know how to test this case.

Here is my comments_controller

```
def destroy
 @comment = @movie.comments.find(params[:id])

if @comment.destroy
  flash[:notice] = 'Comment successfully deleted'
else
  flash[:alert] = 'You are not the author of this comment'
end
redirect_to @movie
end
```

Comment model

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :movie

 validates :body, presence: true
 validates :user, :movie, presence: true
 validates :user, uniqueness: { scope: :movie }

 scope :persisted, -> { where.not(id: nil) }
end
```

User model `has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy` Movie model `has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy` .
I'm using devise and FactoryBot, specs are here:

```
describe "DELETE #destroy" do
  let(:user) { FactoryBot.create(:user) }
  let(:movie) { FactoryBot.create(:movie) }
  let(:other_user) { FactoryBot.create(:user, user_id: 100)}

  it "doesn't delete comment" do
    sign_in(other_user)
    comment = FactoryBot.create(:comment, movie: movie, user: user)

    expect do
      delete :destroy, params: { id: comment.id, movie_id: movie.id }
    end.to_not change(Comment, :count)
    expect(flash[:alert]).to eq "You are not the author of this comment"
  end
end
```

I've got an error `` undefined method `user_id=' for #<User:0x00007fb049644d20> `` and no idea what is the good way to do so.

===EDIT===

Here is my FactoryBot

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password "password"
    confirmed_at 1.day.ago
  end

  factory :unconfirmed_user do
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password "password"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the the users table does not have a `user_id` column which you are trying to use in the other_user instance, the column name is simply `id`:

```
let(:other_user) { FactoryBot.create :user, id: 100 }
```

You can leave out the id entirely, it will get a different id automatically:

```
let(:other_user) { FactoryBot.create :user }
```

Comment: It creates the same user. After your changes the result of test is ```expected #count not to have changed, but did change from 1 to 0```

Comment: Depending on your user factory, the user attributes may be the same, the id will surely not be the same.

Comment: Make sure, that you don't set an id in the user factory. Maybe add its code here.

Comment: I think FactoryBot is defined well, please check my updates

Comment: Ok, the error message you posted your question about is gone now.

Comment: Your test isn't passing because you aren't checking if the user is the owner of the comment. For example in the controller: ```if @comment.user == current_user && @comment.destroy```

Comment: Ops! you're right! I forgot about it, now it's passing, thanks a million